# Qt Creator Sql Update Syntax Error

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, syntax

I am getting sql syntax errors for my update command in qt creator.

```
QSqlQuery q,q2;

for(int r=0; r<rowtablecount; r++){
    q.prepare("update checkdata set "
              "alobs=:alobs,"
              "payee_name=:payee_name,"
              "payee_nature=:payee_nature,"
              "account_code=:account_code,"
              "amount=:amount,"
              "date_paid=:date_paid,"
              "cancel_status=:cancel_status,"
              "reviewer=:reviewer,"
              "preparer=:preparer,"
              "reciever=:reciever,"
              "reviewer_pos=:reviewer_pos,"
              "preparer_pos=:preparer_pos,"
              "reciever_pos=:reciever_pos,"
              "date_delivered=:date_delivered"
              "where check_no = :checkno");
    q.bindValue(":checkno", tabledata[r][2]);
    qDebug() << tabledata[r][2];
    q.bindValue(":alobs",tabledata[r][3]);
    q.bindValue(":payee_name",tabledata[r][4]);
    q.bindValue(":payee_nature",tabledata[r][5]);
    q.bindValue(":account_code",tabledata[r][6]);
    q.bindValue(":amount",tabledata[r][7].toDouble());
    q.bindValue(":date_paid",tabledata[r][10]);
    q.bindValue(":reviewer",reviewer);
    q.bindValue(":preparer",preparer);
    q.bindValue(":reciever",reciever);
    q.bindValue(":reviewer_pos",reviewer_pos);
    q.bindValue(":preparer_pos",preparer_pos);
    q.bindValue(":reciever_pos",reciever_pos);
    q.bindValue(":date_delivered",tabledata[r][9]);
    q.bindValue(":acicn", acic_value);

    q2.prepare("update acic set date_prepared=:date_prepared, total_amount=:total_amount where acic_num=:acic_num");
    q2.bindValue(":date_prepared",tabledata[r][1]);
    q2.bindValue(":total_amount",tabledata[r][8]);
    q2.bindValue(":acic_num", acic_value);

    if(!q.exec()){
        if(q.lastError().isValid())
            qDebug() << q.lastError().text() << " <error " << r;
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error: Entry Failed"),tr("Data Field incorrect."));
    if(!q2.exec()){
        if(q2.lastError().isValid())
            qDebug() << q2.lastError().text() << " <error " << r;
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error: Entry Failed"),tr("Data Field incorrect."));
```

From the above, I get this error, repeated 3 times due to for loop:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check_no = '1248973'' at line 1 QMYSQL: Unable to execute query"

I suspect it is either the writing of the command in prepare, or perhaps reserved word, but I cannot find it.

Ideas on this would be most helpful.

Comment: Give some space before where clause `" where check_no = :checkno" `

Comment: God, know I feel like an idiot. You are completely right. Thanks, none of us saw that one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I am a complete idiot for not seeing this. The error is in the line before "where check_no = :check_no". It just needs a space.

Thanks to Abhik Chakraborty for pointing it out.